# Variável pegando todos os valores da TAG

Tags: javascript

ma API está me devolvendo um token. Eu recebo esse valor no meu html em uma div com o id token. Então eu crio uma variável no meu javascript para capturar o valor desta div, ou seja,

```
var variavel = document.querySelector("#token");
```

E quando tento imprimir no console ele devolve assim:

valor do token
tentei com o .value no final e ele me devolve undefined no console.log
O que preciso fazer para ele me devolver só o valor do token? Grato a quem responder!

Comment: capturar o valor desta div? ou do input? coloca o html aonde o token está aparecendo. completa mais tua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div não possui atributo value e por isso resulta em undefined 
vc pode pegar o token da seguinte maneira:

```
console.log($('#token').text())
```

em js puro

```
var variavel = document.getElementById("token");
console.log(variavel.innerHTML)
```

ex:

```js
console.log($('#token').text())
var variavel = document.getElementById("token");
console.log(variavel.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="token">
teqwufugjfguwef6548446grh
</div>
```

Comment: Então... Parece uma solução, mas você tem um exemplo em javascript mesmo?

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionado trecho em javascript sem jquery

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou aqui, está me retornando nulo

Comment: Vc poderia add aki seu html e javascrip para fcilitar a ajuda